# numpy pad a sequence instead of constant values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to pad a numpy array with a sequence `[0, 1]` along each row. So for example if I have an array as:

```
x = np.random.rand(2, 4)

array([[0.51352468, 0.4274193 , 0.11244252, 0.56787658],
       [0.37855923, 0.80976327, 0.0290558 , 0.87585656]])
```

After the padding operation, it becomes:

```
array([[0.51352468, 0.4274193 , 0.11244252, 0.56787658],
       [0.37855923, 0.80976327, 0.0290558 , 0.87585656],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ]])
```

Currently, the way I am doing this is:

```
padded = np.asarray(x)
padded = np.pad(padded, [(0, 4 - len(padded.shape[0])), (0, 0)], 'constant')
padded[:, -1] = 1.0
```

This seems a bit cumbersome as I pad with zeros and then set the last row to 1. I was wondering if there is a way to do this with just one `numpy.pad` call?

**EDIT**

As you can see from the code above, the function will convert the input to a 4 dimensional object (the input dimension of the array is either 2 or 3 i.e. len(x) == 2 or 3). So, if the input is 2 dimensional, it will add two rows of zeros and then set the last one to 1. if the input is 3 dimensional, it will add a row of zeros and then overwrite to a row of ones.

Comment: Are you always adding exactly 2 rows?

Comment: @unutbu: No, but only the last row will be a row of ones. So it could be either 2 rows or just 1 (a row of ones)

Comment: A matter of terminology: We usually say the number of "dimensions" of an array is the number of axes it has. It looks like your array is always 2 dimensional. Perhaps it would be better to say "the input array either has 2 or 3 rows, and you want the output array to have 4 rows." (i.e. replace the word "dimensional" with "rows".)

Comment: I think you're confusing the concept of dimension with number of rows.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking each column as homogeneous spatial coordinates.

Comment: Because of its generality `np.pad` inputs can be cumbersome, but I only see one call.  `np.pad(x, [[0,n],[0,0]], 'constant')`.  But since you are only adding rows on one side, `pad` is in a sense over kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a suitable case to use `np.pad`. As an alternative you can use `append` and `repeat`.

```
In [48]: a, b = x.shape
In [49]: np.append(x, np.repeat([[0],[1]], b, axis=1), axis=0)
Out[49]: 
array([[ 0.2129145 ,  0.68606654,  0.53354256,  0.19112299],
       [ 0.11836389,  0.71193408,  0.49222709,  0.60790186],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

If you want to use a variable for number of zero rows that you're inserting you can use `np.zeros()` with an inplace unpacking trick as follows:

```
In [84]: np.append(x, np.repeat([*np.zeros(z_num)[:, None],[1]], b, axis=1), axis=0) # b is x.shape[1]
```

Which `z_num` represents the number of zero rows. You can then simply change this variable based on the size of your input array.

Example:

```
In [84]: np.append(x, np.repeat([*np.zeros(0)[:, None],[1]], b, axis=1), axis=0)
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0.38922514,  0.75096968,  0.71939798,  0.84233763],
       [ 0.8055875 ,  0.29738511,  0.57563254,  0.45073955],
       [ 0.94241764,  0.27107424,  0.24536665,  0.60723426],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])

In [85]: 

In [85]: np.append(x, np.repeat([*np.zeros(3)[:, None],[1]], b, axis=1), axis=0)
Out[85]: 
array([[ 0.38922514,  0.75096968,  0.71939798,  0.84233763],
       [ 0.8055875 ,  0.29738511,  0.57563254,  0.45073955],
       [ 0.94241764,  0.27107424,  0.24536665,  0.60723426],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is it possible to use it so that if the input x is 3 dimensional that it only adds a row of ones, else it adds rows of zeros till the last one which is a row of ones....

Comment: @Luca This is completely another question. Please, add these to your question with a little bit more clarification.

Comment: I have added some detail about this.

Comment: This trick is awesome. Thanks. Took me 15 minutes to figure it out though!

Comment: `np.append` with axis parameter is just a call to `np.concatenate` (check its code).  I don't like the function; it confuses too many new users.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah axis is always confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be simpler (to read) if you simply allocate a 2D array of zeros,
assign ones to the last row, and copy `x` into the padded array:

```
import numpy as np
def pad(x):
    nrows, ncols = x.shape
    padded = np.zeros((4, ncols))
    padded[-1, :] = 1
    padded[:nrows, :] = x
    return padded

nrows, ncols = np.random.randint(2, 4), 4
x = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)
padded = pad(x)
```

yields a padded array such as

```
array([[ 0.38746512,  0.23166218,  0.97459752,  0.37565333],
       [ 0.05774882,  0.44061104,  0.06661526,  0.26714634],
       [ 0.00805322,  0.30201519,  0.71373347,  0.08288743],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

or

```
array([[ 0.68343436,  0.6108459 ,  0.84325679,  0.10912022],
       [ 0.547983  ,  0.7543816 ,  0.02411474,  0.02711809],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

depending on the number of rows `x` has (which this assumes is <= 4).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here's a way of padding with both the 0 and 1 with just `np.pad`:

Write a little padding function.

```
def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    # print(vector, pad_width,iaxis)
    if iaxis==0: vector[-1] = 1
    return vector
```

This is just enough of a change from the example in the docs to work here.  The `print` line was helpful in understanding what `pad` is passing it.

So the action is determined by that 2nd pad width number:

```
In [31]: np.pad(x, [[0,1],[0,0]],pad_with)
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
In [32]: np.pad(x, [[0,2],[0,0]],pad_with)
Out[32]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
In [33]: np.pad(x, [[0,4],[0,0]],pad_with)
Out[33]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

With the print on:

```
In [27]: np.pad(x, [[0,1],[0,0]],pad_with)
[0 4 0] (0, 1) 0
[1 5 0] (0, 1) 0
[2 6 0] (0, 1) 0
[3 7 0] (0, 1) 0
[0 1 2 3] (0, 0) 1
[4 5 6 7] (0, 0) 1
[1 1 1 1] (0, 0) 1
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

So `pad` is iterating over each row and column, and passing to this function the 0 padded `vector`.  The function can then modify that, even changing the interior values.  Lots of generality here, but over kill for this simple problem.